# Recuperar DB do Xampp no OSX

Tags: xampp

Atualizei meu Macbook e o xampp não abriu mais, então baixei a última versão do xampp, consegui importar meus projetos para a pasta HTDOCS, porem não consigo importar a pasta do mysql dentro do "var" onde APARENTEMENTE está localizado os meus DB.. baixei o XAMPP 7.3.12, alguma idéia de como importar esses bancos do outro XAMPP que não abre mais??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi instalando a versão de instalação do xampp e nao a versão de VM, assim ele instalou por cima e os bancos voltaram a aparecer